How to prove non-stationarity in the wide sense for a time series process?
I'm working with the following time series process:
$
x_t = x_{t-1} + c^2 x_{t-2} - c^2 x_{t-3} + \epsilon_t, \quad t = 0, \pm 1, \dots
$
where $\{\epsilon_t\}$ is a white noise process with $\mathbb{E}[\epsilon_t] = 0$ and $Var[\epsilon_t] = \sigma_\epsilon^2$. I need to show that this process is non-stationary in the wide sense for all values of $c$.
What I understand so far:
To prove non-stationarity in the wide sense, I need to check the following conditions:

The mean of the process, $\mathbb{E}[x_t]$, is constant.
The variance of the process, $\text{Var}[x_t]$, is constant.
The autocovariance, $\text{Cov}(x_t, x_{t+h})$, depends only on the lag $h$ (and not on $t$).

I was able to verify that the first two conditions hold for this process. However, I am stuck on the third condition, which involves showing whether or not the covariance depends on $t$.
I derived a recursion formula for the autocovariance $\gamma(h) = \text{Cov}(x_t, x_{t+h})$ using the process definition. However, I am unsure how to use it to analyze the dependency of $\gamma(h)$ on $t$. My attempts at simplifying the recursion have not clarified whether the covariance depends on $t$ or only on $h$.
How can I explicitly show that the autocovariance $\text{Cov}(x_t, x_{t+h})$ depends on $t$ for this process? Is there a standard approach to use the recursion formula to identify this dependency? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
Let me know if further details are needed!

Hi: If the question is referring to the $\Delta x_t$ process, then you've got relevant questions  ( that myself or someone else can try to explain ). But, if it's referring to the $x_t$ process, then the process is not stationary because the $x_{t-1}$ on the other side makes it non-stationary because  it's a  unit root process  so the mean is not constant.
